# How do I create a strongly typed model and use it in the cshtml file as opposed to a dynamic one?

Tags: c#, razor

I am following [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx) article and I believe it uses a dynamic model, but I want to create a strongly typed model and use it, but I am having a hard time.  Does anyone have an example, I already created a class with a few properties and made several instances of the class that I want to loop through in my cshtml file and generate the output.

Here is the cshtml file:

```
@* Generator : Template TypeVisibility : Internal *@
@*@model*@

<table>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr><tr><th>Type</th></tr><tr><th>Failed</th></tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr><td>@item.Name</td><td>@Model.Type</td><td>@Model.Failed</td></tr>  
}
</table>
```

Here is the Failures.cs file:

```
namespace RazorEmailTemplate.Models
{
    public class PMSFailures
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime Failed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is Program.cs:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var template = new RazorTemplate
            {
                Model = new[] {
                new {Name = "Tru", Type=1, Failed= DateTime.UtcNow},
                new {Name = "Op", Type=2,Failed= DateTime.UtcNow},
                new {Name = "Sy", Type=3,Failed= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-16)},
                new {Name = "Tr", Type=4,Failed= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-3)}
                }
            };


            Console.WriteLine(template.TransformText());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

The RazorTemplate.cshtml has RazorGenerator as its Custom Tool and it generates a file called RazorTemplate.generated.cs.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the article you are using? most examples I have seen on the web use strongly typed models...

Comment: Can you add a link to the article, and explain at which stage exactly you have troubles?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to add the link. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the oracle... I have decided [this is a good example](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/13/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-strongly-typed-views-in-razor.aspx).

Comment: It's hardly full. Doesn't show the advantage of using ****For html generic helpers